What is the UserRecord (Contex) equivent in V2 cloud functions type interface?
I am trying to type my fucntinos and cannot find the type defenction in the new api , any idea what is the new name for the interface ?
could this

type AuthType = functionsHttps.CallableRequest['auth'];

be equivalent to

import { UserRecord } from 'firebase-functions/v1/auth';

since there is no way i am finding the type in /v2


interface Request {
  data: CreateUserData; // local interface 
  auth?: any; // UserRecord in V1
}

// Documentation: V2 Create Data Functions with custom claims.
export const createUserV2 = functionsHttps.onCall(async (request: Request) => {
  const uid = request.auth?.uid;
  const authData = request.auth;
  const { userType, privacySettings } = request.data;
  
  // rest of the codde
})




You're not typing the request object correctly.  The first argument to a v2 callable function is a CallableRequest object (not a Request object as you have now).
The usage information you're looking for is covered using examples in the documentation, assuming you have typed it correctly:
// Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
const uid = request.auth.uid;
const name = request.auth.token.name || null;
const picture = request.auth.token.picture || null;
const email = request.auth.token.email || null;

There is no context object available.  Everything is in the CallableRequest object.

so it should look like this onCall(async (request: CallableRequest) => {})
